# Python Eve - Creating a task scheduling API

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, api-design, eve

I am writing a task scheduling web service using the python framework Eve.

I have a mongo database containing tasks.

I use Eve to expose that database to workers / clients.

The system I have in place so far looks something like this.

The workers / clients make a GET request to an endpoint that returns a number of tasks.

`GET /tasks`

Upon completion of each task, the workers make a PATCH request to the link provided by Eve.

For example:

`PATCH /tasks/6109f55abf5cfd6ab6d22312`

The problem I am having is, the same task is scheduled multiple times, given to multiple workers. This is why on the server side I get responses that look like this.

```
"PATCH /tasks/6109f55abf5cfd6ab6d22312 HTTP/1.1" 200
"PATCH /tasks/6109f55abf5cfd6ab6d22312 HTTP/1.1" 412
```

What is the correct way to ensure each task is assigned to one worker only, in pythons Eve framework?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

Client side, I use node and my request looks something like this:

```
fetch(tasks_endpoint).then(perform_tasks).catch(task_error)
```

Reporting is done in a similar fashion:

```
fetch(report_endpoint, {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'If-Match': etag
    },
    body: report_body
});
```

Both requests work. My problem is the GET request, for getting tasks, gets the same tasks for all clients, instead of unique tasks for each of them.

Comment: How do you make requests? Can we see relevant client code please?

Comment: Sure. I have a node client. I do something like this: `                fetch(tasks_endpoint)
                    .then(perform_tasks)` I am able to GET the tasks and report ( PATCH ) them. The problem is, I get the same tasks on my workers.